# Как правильно: разжим или розжим?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать слово: рАзжим или рОзжим?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: разжим.

Проверять правильность написания можно на сайте [Грамота](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A1%D0%82%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A0%C2%B7%D0%A0%C2%B6%D0%A0%D1%91%D0%A0%D1%98&all=x)

Answer (score 1):

**разжи́м** *м.*

**1.** *Процесс действия по гл. **разжимАть, разжимАться.*** Результат такого действия.
 **2.** Инструмент, приспособление, служащее для разжимания чего-либо.
(Разжим-кусачки, гидравлический разжим, разжим автономный электрогидравлический...)

*Приставка: **раз-**; корень: **-жим-*** [Тихонов, 1996].

*Приставка **раз- (рас-) / роз- (рос-).***
Вопреки общему правилу, в этой приставке на месте безударного гласного пишется буква **А**, а под ударением — **О**.
Например: *разда́ть* (ср. ро́здал, ро́зданный), *расписа́ние, распи́ска* (ро́спись), *разыгра́ть* (ро́зыгрыш).
[**§ 40. Приставка раз- (рас-) / роз- (рос-**)](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=5657)

[*Разма́х, разбро́д, разде́л, разве́дка, разгово́р, разгу́л.*]